# Unable to locate ft_min_word_len variable in my local mysql server

Tags: mysql, server-variables

I was trying to edit the MySQL server variable ft_min_word_len, but unfortunately i could not find the file location on my hard disk containing these settings
I looked for the files my.ini and my.cnf in MySQL installation directory, in c:\windows directory and in 'C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\' server 5.5 and any other possible location.

I found only one file my.ini in MySQL installation directory (c:\MySQL), but this file contains no such settings.

I look through phpmyadmin and i found that variable in 'Server variables and settings' section, i also find this variable in information_schema under GLOBAL_VARIABLES table.

But i couldn't find it in any file on my windows 7 system which is 64bit and i have installed 64bit specific MySQL

one thing i also noticed that there was no file for information_schema in 'C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\data' but for other database there is corresponding file in it.

Hope for some helpful answer

Answer (score 2):

MySQL config file would usually be found on Windows under C:\Windows\my.ini and on Linux under
/etc/my.cnf

If you doesn't get any below line into file and then you can add it, then restart your mysql server.

```
[mysqld]
ft_min_word_len = 3
```

Comment: I have my.ini in c:\MySQL which is the default installation directory

Comment: it's fine. you can add above lines into file and restart mysql service.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't mandatory to specify every single variable in the settings file. MySQL will use the hard-coded default values when you don't set a value. Just add a new line to the file.

As about file location, it should be in the base dir:

```
mysql> SELECT @@basedir;
+------------------------------------------+
| @@basedir                                |
+------------------------------------------+
| C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0\ |
+------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: @Vicario --Thanks for the info. So what is the best way to change them??